# Strange black border when using SKCropNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, crop

I'm working on a game with SpriteKit and I have a square SKSpriteNode whose corners I want to make round. I can't use an SKShapeNode because I want to eventually add a gradient to it. So I decided to use as SKCropNode to crop it, but when I do so, a weird black border like this appears:

[image]

If I don't try to crop it, it looks like this:

[image]

This is my code I am using to create and crop it:

```
    spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: color.skColor, size: CGSize(width: TileSize, height: TileSize))

    let borderRadius: CGFloat = 2
    let roundPath = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRect(x: -TileSize / 2, y: -TileSize / 2, width: TileSize, height: TileSize), borderRadius, borderRadius, nil)

    let mask = SKShapeNode()
    mask.path = roundPath
    mask.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    mask.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    let cropNode = SKCropNode()
    cropNode.maskNode = mask

    let shadow = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: TileSize, height: TileSize))
    shadow.colorBlendFactor = 1
    shadow.alpha = 0.25

    let radius: CGFloat = 3.5
    shadow.position = CGPoint(x: radius / 2, y: radius / 2)

    let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
    effectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: [kCIInputRadiusKey: radius])
    effectNode.zPosition = spriteNode!.zPosition - 1
    effectNode.addChild(shadow)

    let bluredTile = SKShapeNode(path: roundPath)
    bluredTile.addChild(effectNode)

    cropNode.addChild(spriteNode!)

    addChild(bluredTile)
    addChild(cropNode)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Try to set bluredTile.strokeColor = .clearColor(). Note that whenever you create SKShapeNode it has lineWidth property set to 1, and strokeColor set to white. You can set lineWidth to zero, but keep in mind that this will affect on what mask.calculateAccumulatedFrame() returns.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: What iOS you have installed ? Which Xcode do you use? I am on iOS 9.1 and Xcode 7.1.1 and it actually works. Both on device and simulators... Also I've used empty SpriteKit game template to test it...

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.2, and I've tested in on the iPhone 5s simulator as well as an up to date physical iPhone 6s

Comment: Try to set mask.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor() as well...Also try everything on an empty project just to be sure that the issue is not related the rest of your code.

Comment: Setting `mask.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()` made the border white, which is much more tolerable and I think I can work with it. Thanks!